# How to install vim with clipboard support on Fedora?

Tags: vim, fedora, clipboard

I'm using Fedora Linux and don't have the ability to copy text from vim into the system clipboard (which I should be able to do by using the + or * register, though I'm not sure which). If I type this at the command line:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

... the relevant line says `-xterm_clipboard`, when what I want to see is `+xterm clipboard`.

How can I add this support? Do I have to compile something (please say no!) or can I just `yum install` something?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

vim in Fedora is compiled without any X support in order to minimize the number of dependencies it has. You'll need to use gvim instead, in the `vim-X11` package.

Comment: Note that while you'll need the version of Vim that supports X, you don't need to run it as an X application--you can run it in a terminal as `gvim -v`. That will launch Vim in vi or terminal mode but with access to the X clipboard. You can make this easier with an alias: `alias vim='gvim -v'`.

Comment: @garyjohn - awesome! That works perfectly.

Comment: @garyjohn - ...and, your awesome tip about running graphical vim on the command line has come in handy yet again, this time on a Mac. `mvim -v` also gives access to the system clipboard. Thanks!

Comment: Fedora package vim-X11 ships also binary `vimx`, so you can run that one within X11 if you don't want to alias.

Comment: @LukasT indeed great point - this works perfectly. This [Vi.SE answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2065/11986) suggests the same.

Comment: Excellent!  In Arch Linux, the default Vim lacks system support [per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard, :echo has('clipboard') returns 0]. Installing Gvim,instead of Vim, provides a Vim version that returns 1 for that command.